# Drawing procedural lines on top of a texture avoiding aliasing in glsl

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl, antialiasing

My goal is to draw white lines over an asphalt road. Since the properties of the road change, there cannot be just a texture representing both asphalt and white lines.
The current approach is to apply the asphalt texture and code some information in the other two texture coordinates. In a pixel shader, reading those coordinates, I decide whether that fragment should be white or not.

This results in high levels of aliasing. And that’s the problem I want to try to solve.

I have been changing the “whiteness” of the line applying smoothstep or linear interpolation. I have also changed the width and color according to distance from camera. This helps a little bit, but at far away distances, there are still ugly aliased lines.

How would you go on doing this? Would it be better to have a texture representing a smoothed white line and accessing the texels? Should I implement a bilinear filter accessing neighboring texels?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the "the propeties of the road change so I can't use a texture representing asphalt and white lines" bit? Why can't you just pick the correct texture from a pre-rendered set and stitch those together? Perhaps we can suggest a way to overcome the problems you have been encounting in that area, defaulting the "drawing white lines" problem to ordinary texturing.

Comment: As for the actual question, you could try using the decal technique as sketched by Humus (http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=84), but applying it to the white lines only (as you already have the asphalt bits covered).

Comment: Thanks @Paul-Jan
I’ll check that link thoroughly, seems promising.
As of the other question:
The roads can be edited at runtime by the user (width, number of lanes, junctions, painted signes…).
There has to be a way of doing it only creating a bunch of textures and attaching them correctly at the geometry but I thought that it would be easier and more flexible to change codification (passed through extra texture coordinates) . I might have taken the wrong approach there, but so far, besides aliasing, I have been having good results whit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use 2 textures with 2 coordinates.

1. Small seamless asphalt texture tiled on the road polygon.
2. Mark texture with alpha that you will place on the middle of this polygon (with texture coordinate offset)

Or you can create extra polygons in the middle of the road for marks to avoid any aliasing.

To make it all looks real you can apply [Texture Bombing](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch20.html) with dirt and cracks.

Comment: Thanks @JAre, 
That’s pretty much the standard approach that I thought I could implement, but that would mean redoing most of the code on road drawing (which is a possibility still).
Just so I can explore drawing on shaders a little bit further:
Is there a way I can take asphalt color by sampling the texture and then calculate if that fragment is part of a white line and apply that result to the final color in an anti-aliased way? Is that possible at all? If so, would you say is worth it? Would applying post-process AA help? Or might be better redoing the whole thing by using textures?

Comment: @user1854147 For post-process AA you need edge(normal\depth slope), right? You can try to make it looks sharper with post processing. But normally it's done with standard texture mapping. You can do it with shaders in procedural way but it's hard to write and even harder to extend. For example you can test fragment (in fragment shader) if it's far enough from both sides(based on texture coordinate value) then it is white. But in this way your shader may grow too fat especially if you use branching. Also you can implement stripes as separate geometry with small ofset from the road